# How fast can through hole PCBs run?

Tags: pcb-design, high-speed

I'm trying to rate the speed of my pathetic attempts at electronics against what's historically possible.

So sticking specifically to through hole construction, how fast can a soldered PCB operate?  The fastest I've personally done is about 5 MHz (analogue) and I wonder where this falls on the speed spectrum.

I found this:-

[image: motherboard]

It's   an AMD 586-133 motherboard,and in the top right you can see through hole memory chips. They're UM61256FK-15's with (I'm guessing) a 15ns access. There's also a DIP package squeezed in between two of the ISA sockets in the bottom left corner.  And lot's of through hole bypassing capacitors and parallel resistor networks.  You can also see other major components surface mounted, so I guess that this board was designed somewhere around the transition to SMDs.  Surely through hole PCBs can't go to 133 MHz can they?  And is there a different maximum for analogue and digital circuits?

Comment: Do radio frequencies count? Plenty of kits with through hole components for transmitters / receivers

Comment: Modern radio devices use some though-hole and operate past 1GHz.

Comment: Duh - I never thought of my tranny or old TV...

Comment: View any via as 1 nanoHenry inductance. At 1GHz, that is +j6.3 ohms. What will 6.3 ohms, reactive, do in your circuit?

Comment: I've worked on boards with through-hole ("press-fit") backplane conectors carrying 10GHz differential signals. These are short leads but definitely not SMT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of processors usually runs quite a bit faster than anything on the board. I would guess the fastest buses on that board are probably running on a 33 MHz clock.

In general the most important thing with high-frequency work is to keep return current loop area low. You do that by running the tracks closely above or below a reference plane, avoiding changes of reference plane as much as possible, avoiding cutting up your reference planes as much as possible and tying together your reference planes (either directly or with capacitors) as close as possible to where tracks change reference plane.

Unfortunately to do that well really requires at least 6 layers. In mass production PCBs are dirt cheap, so a 6-layer board doesn't break the bank but for one-off work the costs get seriously painful.

The trouble with through-hole ICs is that they end up with significant connection lengths inside the package which unless it is a fancy specially designed package have no reference plane, pushing up the loop area. The higher the pin count gets the worse this gets.

Though-hole connectors don't suffer nearly as badly from this issue and have remained in widespread use to this day, even for very fast connectors. PCI-X puts a multipoint bus with a 133 MHz clock over through-hole connectors. PCIe runs at 8 gigatransitions per second (giving a "worst case fundamental frequency" of 4 GHz) over through-hole connectors.

Answer (score 3):

Through-hole components are more limited in speed than surface-mount ones, because they need longer pins and bigger packages. As a result, the PCB itself has to be bigger, and longer traces hinder the performance even more. However, for a reasonably-sized PCB, these factors only matter for frequencies in tens or a hundred of MHz.

Another factor is that many fast-grade chips simply don't exist in DIP packages, which makes through-hole designs slower in general. Though this isn't a limitation of trough-hole assembly itself.

Answer (score 3):

Focusing mainly on connectors (it's much harder to design THT components with minimal parasitics/constant impedance), consider that many high speed connectors come in through-hole:

- SATA 3 - 6 Gbps
- USB 3.0 - 5 Gbps, possibly 10 Gbps w/ USB 3.1 (not sure if there are THT connectors for 3.1)
- HDMI 2.0 (6G/lane, soon to be 12G/lane, not sure if HDMI 2.1 connectors will be THT though)
- DisplayPort (5.4G/lane, possibly 8.1G/lane)
- PCIe 3.1 (8 GT/s)
- DDR4 (3.2 MT/s)

..and so on.

So with proper connector and PCB design, through-hole is not mutually exclusive with middleish-high bandwidth (6 Gbps) circuits: connectors must be carefully designed to preserve characteristic impedance through the length of the connector, and the traces on the PCB should be routed to minimize the stub length (highspeed lanes are typically routed from the opposite side of the connector to keep the stubs created by the pins as short as possible).

So while using entirely THT components is pretty limiting (both due to parasitics and size, which is why high speed components are simply not available in THT packages), a high speed design with SMT components and some THT components, typically connectors, can easily operate at many tens of Gbps, at least.